# Trying to extract nested JSON data to javascript/trying to eliminate keys in JSON but keep the data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vuejs3, apexcharts

So I need to make a chart from my JSON data that looks like this

```
{

    "batch": [{

            "timestamp": 738127638,
            "data": {
                "senzor1": 525,
                "senzor2": 625,
                "senzor3": 425,
                "senzor4": 325
            }
        },
        {

            "timestamp": 738127640,
            "data": {
                "senzor1": 528,
                "senzor2": 628,
                "senzor3": 428,
                "senzor4": 328
            }
        },
        {

            "timestamp": 738127658,
            "data": {
                "senzor1": 535,
                "senzor2": 635,
                "senzor3": 435,
                "senzor4": 335
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Thing is that I don't know how to get data from the senzors withouth hardcoding something like

```
  for (let i = 0; i < this.batch.length; i++) {
              this.ts.push(this.batch[i].data.senzor1)

            }
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this

I have also tried this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.batch.length; i++) {
             this.ts.push(...Object.values(this.batch[i].data))

           }
```

but this extracts everything into the same array and doesn't seperate data by senzors

NOTE: I'm working with Vue3 and apexcharts

and this is the entire code

```
<template>
  <div id="wrapper">

   <p>{{batch}}</p>
   <p>{{s1}}</p>
   
   
  <div id="chart-line">
   <apexchart
      width="500"
      type="line"
      :options="chartOptions"
      :series="series"
      ></apexchart>
  </div>
      <div id="chart-line">
   <apexchart
      width="500"
      type="line"
      :options="chartOptions"
      :series="seriesLine2"
      ></apexchart>
  </div>
     
     
  </div>
</template>
```

```
<script>

import VueApexCharts from "vue3-apexcharts";
export default {

  components: {
    
    apexchart: VueApexCharts,
    
  },
    data: function() {
    return {
      batch:[],
      s1:[],
      s2:[],
      s3:[],
      s4:[],
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          id: "vuechart-example",
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories: [],
        },
      },
      series: [
        {
          name: "series-1",
          data: [],
        },  
      ],
      seriesLine2:[{
        
          name: "series-2",
          data: [],
        
          
      }]
};
    },
      methods:{ 
 
        async fetchBatch(){ 
            const res=await fetch('http://localhost:5000/batch')

            const data= await res.json()
            return data
        },

    
    },
 


    async created(){ 
    
            this.batch=await this.fetchBatch()
            console.log(this.batch)

               for (let i = 0; i < this.batch.length; i++) {
                this.s1.push(this.batch[i].data.senzor1)
                this.s2.push(this.batch[i].data.senzor2)
                this.s3.push(this.batch[i].data.senzor3)
                this.s4.push(this.batch[i].data.senzor4)
              }

            this.series=[{name: "series-1",data: this.s1}]
            this.seriesLine2=[{name: "series-2",data: this.s2}]
            
      

        }

    

    
}







</script>
```

EDIT! Solved with
  `this.test=Object.values(this.test)`

thanks for everyone who helped

Comment: whats is expected output

Comment: honestly. I have no idea I am just at a roadblock RN

Answer (score 2):

You could easily group sensor data using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like below:

```js
let batch = [{

    "timestamp": 738127638,
    "data": {
      "senzor1": 525,
      "senzor2": 625,
      "senzor3": 425,
      "senzor4": 325
    }
  },
  {

    "timestamp": 738127640,
    "data": {
      "senzor1": 528,
      "senzor2": 628,
      "senzor3": 428,
      "senzor4": 328
    }
  },
  {

    "timestamp": 738127658,
    "data": {
      "senzor1": 535,
      "senzor2": 635,
      "senzor3": 435,
      "senzor4": 335
    }
  }
];

let grouped = batch.reduce((sensors, ts) => {
  let {
    data
  } = ts;
  for (let sen in data) {
    sensors[sen] = [...(sensors[sen] || []), {time: ts.timestamp, log:data[sen]}]
  };
  return sensors;
}, {});
console.log(grouped)
```

Comment: this works fine but I still have to deal with the keys, which is my primary headache because IDK how to code something that won't rely on my calling specific stuff like ``` grouped.senzor1```

Comment: Where in this code have you seen that specific stuff? it's all variable names.

Comment: I edited my original post so you can have the full context... I'm sorry I'm not very good at explaining what 'm doing

Answer (score 1):

You could just use object.keys to pull the individual senzor names from that data object

```js
let test = {

    "batch": [{

            "timestamp": 738127638,
            "data": {
                "senzor1": 525,
                "senzor2": 625,
                "senzor3": 425,
                "senzor4": 325
            }
        },
        {

            "timestamp": 738127640,
            "data": {
                "senzor1": 528,
                "senzor2": 628,
                "senzor3": 428,
                "senzor4": 328
            }
        },
        {

            "timestamp": 738127658,
            "data": {
                "senzor1": 535,
                "senzor2": 635,
                "senzor3": 435,
                "senzor4": 335
            }
        }
    ]
}

let res = {}
test.batch.forEach(e=>{
  Object.keys(e.data).forEach(senzor=>{
    res[senzor]=res[senzor]||[]
    res[senzor].push({ts:e.timestamp, val:e.data[senzor]})
    })
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: thing is that I might get different senors or a different number of senzors in the future. I have no idea how to go about doing this!

Comment: The number or name of the senzors won’t make any difference to object.keys. As long as the structure of the original data doesn’t change, logic like this should work to get you what you need